# How to add and subtract list data in state on checkbox check and unchecked in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Here in this screen I am maping array ("above array) value with checkbox ,there are some amout "data.TransactionAmount" I have to calculate the sum of all and send to next screen,
but if I uncheck any of the list amount should minus .Like there are 3 values - 1050+1050+1050 =3150 and if I unchecked single value then it should be 1050+1050-1050=2100 and it should updae in below button.
If i am uncheking single list all list is getting unchecked .
in state "sum" im getting total sum be default and value is coming in button . but if I do uncheck any of the list ,value should minus .
Please help , Thanks ,
Below link is refrence what i am implementing .

https://xd.adobe.com/view/d733da48-5d0c-47ca-7ded-6fc8f0f609cf-a102/screen/37cb15c6-b56a-4b98-8612-e9b86d0dd34c/Android-Mobile-147/?fullscreen

```
 // Below is the array value 
    financialTransactionDetail: Array(3)
    0:
    AdjustedAmount: "0"
    NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
    TransactionAmount: 1050
    1:
    AdjustedAmount: "0"
    NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
    TransactionAmount: 1050

    2:
    AdjustedAmount: "0"
    NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
    Status: "Unpaid"
    TransactionAmount: 1050

    this.state = {
          title: 'Payments against invoice',
          icon: 'sim',
          mobile:navigation.state.params.customer.service.serviceNumber,
          isChecked:true,
          sum :financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail.reduce((a, c) => { return a + c.TransactionAmount}, 0),
          transactionAmount :''
        }

         handleChange(key , value){

        this.setState({
          isChecked:!this.state.isChecked})
      }

      handleChangeSum = (sum) => {
        this.setState({
          sum: sum
        });
      }

     { !_.isEmpty(financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail) && financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail.map(
                        (data, index) => {
                          return(
                            <View key={index} style={{flexDirection:'row', padding:10, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                          <View style={{paddingRight:10, marginRight:10}}>
                            <CheckBox style={styles.checkBox} color="#00678f" checked={this.state.isChecked} onPress={() =>this.handleChange()}/>
                          </View>
                          <View style={{flexDirection:'column',flex:1, padding:10, borderWidth:1, borderColor:'lightgrey', borderRadius:10}}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
                              {!this.state.isChecked && <RegularText text={`₦ ${data.TransactionAmount}`} style={{paddingBottom:10, paddingRight:5}}/>}
                              <SmallText text="From 1-Jan-2019 to 31-Jan-2019" style={{paddingBottom:10}}/>
                            </View>
                            {this.state.isChecked && 
                            <RegularText text={`₦ ${data.TransactionAmount}`} style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
                              </RegularText>
                            }
                          </View>
                        </View>
                          )
                        }
                      )
                      }

                      <View>
                  <Button full onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('PaymentOptionsContainer',sum)}>
                    <Text>Receive Payment ({sum})</Text>
                  </Button>
                </View>
```

Thanks

Comment: I see that there are more answers so I just put the link here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nyalzx

Comment: Thank you so much .. But This array value will come dynamically

Comment: No problem. At some point it will be in the state of the component so it will work just the way it's working in the snippet..

Comment: Thanks .let me try that also  :)

Comment: I updated the snippet a bit. Maybe it more suitable now.

Comment: ok... juts saw , here in my code default value should come addition of all amount ,then on checkbox  state update

Comment: Do you mean this `sum :financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail.reduce((a, c) => { return a + c.TransactionAmount}, 0)`? on the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of is isChecked use checked which is array like below in state

```
// Instead
isChecked: true
// Use below one
checked: financialTransactionDetail.map(() => true)
```

Now let the checkbox point based on index like below

```
// Instead
<CheckBox style={styles.checkBox} color="#00678f" checked={this.state.isChecked} onPress={() =>this.handleChange()}/>
// Use Below one
<CheckBox style={styles.checkBox} color="#00678f" checked={this.state.checked[index]} onPress={() =>this.handleChange(index)}/>
```

Now change handle onchange of checkbox

```
handleChange(index){
  let newChecked = [...checked];
  newChecked[index] = !newChecked[index];
  this.setState({checked: newChecked})
}
```

Finally based on checked array calculate sum

```
let sum = 0;
this.state.checked.map((value, index) => {
  if(value) {
    sum += financialTransactionDetail[i].TransactionAmount;
  }
});
```

Comment: getting error "checked: financialTransactionDetail.map(() => true)

Comment: financialTransactionDetail.map  is not a  function

Comment: checked:  financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail.map(() => true)

Comment: I also realized same  , let me try

Comment: let sum = 0;
this.state.checked.map((value, index) => {
  if(value) {
    sum += financialTransactionDetail[i].TransactionAmount;
  }
});

Comment: getting error first I is not defined changed i to index now coming TransactionAmount  undefined

Comment: let sum = 0; this.state.checked.map((value, index) => { if(value) { sum += financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail[index].TransactionAmount; } });

Comment: Thanks .value is coming but , 105010501050 and after uncheck its coming 10501050

Comment: it should be the sum of all value

Comment: the value is string so it is getting appended instead of adding

Comment: got it... you are great  :)

Comment: let sum = 0; this.state.checked.map((value, index) => { if(value) { sum += parseInt(financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail[index].TransactionAmount); } });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197879/discussion-between-abhigyan-gaurav-and-mabhijith95a10).

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be very involved with libraries and proprietary code.

I'm sure you're just looking for some methods that can help update the total balance upon checking/unchecking an amount.

Here's a working sandbox I've made for you that you can replicate: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-swanson-2ccxo

Working code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const data = [{ amount: 1050 }, { amount: 1025 }, { amount: 1000 }];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    total: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const dataWithCheckedProp = data.map(item => {
      return { ...item, checked: true };
    });

    let total = data.reduce((total, item) => total + item.amount, 0);

    this.setState({
      data: dataWithCheckedProp,
      total: total
    });
  }

  handleOnChange = index => {
    const dataCopy = [...this.state.data];

    dataCopy[index].checked = !dataCopy[index].checked;

    let balance = dataCopy.reduce((total, item) => {
      if (item.checked) {
        total = total + item.amount;
      }
      return total;
    }, 0);

    this.setState({
      data: dataCopy,
      total: balance
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { data, total } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={item.checked}
                onChange={() => this.handleOnChange(index)}
              />
              <label>{item.amount}</label>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <h4>Total: {total}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

In summary, here are the steps you need to take:

1. You really just need to give each object in the
   `financialTransactionDetail` array a `checked` property. See logic
   in `componentDidMount()` where we clone the financial data array and give each object a new prop.
2. In your change-handler function, have it accept an `index`, which
   refers to the item that was toggled. The `index` will be passed via
   the 2nd parameter of `.map()`. See `handleOnChange()`logic
3. Within `handleOnChange()`, use the `index` to find the object within
   the data-set and simply toggle its `checked` boolean value. Then
   with the updated array, have your `.reduce()` function add only
   those items that are checked.